# Can a finite state transducer emit $\epsilon$?

Tags: finite-automata, transducers

Can a deterministic finite state transducer output ϵ (epsilon) ?

> A Deterministic Finite-state Transducer (DFT) is a device much like a
>   DFA, except that its purpose is not to accept strings or languages but
>   to transform input strings into output strings. Informally, it starts
>   in a designated initial state & moves from state to state , depending
>   on the input , just as DFA does. On each step, however it emits a
>   string of the symbols of the alphabet (zero or one or more than one
>   symbols)depending on the current state & the input symbol. The state
>   diagram of a DFT looks like that of a DFA, except that the label on an
>   arrow looks like a/w, which means “if the input symbol is a, follow
>   this arrow and emit output w”.

Comment: Please acknowledge the source of the text you've quoted.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The quote says that the machine emits "zero or one or more than one symbols". Emitting zero symbols is emitting $\varepsilon$.